# Gridview Sorting c# on Edit Button Click Not Working

Tags: c#, sorting, gridview

I click on edit button without sorting my column header in the `DataGridView`, this works fine, I can edit the row and values in a drop down fine.

However, when I sort the column and then hit edit - it allows me to edit the original `DataGridView` and not the sorted version.

I think its an issue binding the datagridview on the edit button as its not storing the sort order anywhere but can't seem to figure out how to save the sort session and apply it in the `GetgvCaseListData()` method.

The below code works fine before sorting, but breaks when the `GridView` is sorted and edit button is clicked:

```
protected void GetgvCaseListData()
{
    string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].cr_fe_list", cn); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subteamno", SubTeam);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        gvCaseList.DataSource = ds;
        gvCaseList.DataBind();
        ViewState["dirState"] = ds;
        ViewState["sortdr"] = "Asc";

    }
    else
    {
        noresultsvalidation.Visible = true;
        gvCaseList.DataSource = ds;
        gvCaseList.DataBind();
        ViewState["dirState"] = ds;
        ViewState["sortdr"] = "Asc";
    }

protected void gvCaseList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    MeasurementID = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "MeasurementID"));
    string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    if (e.Row.Cells[10].Text == "OVERDUE")
    {
        e.Row.Cells[10].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        e.Row.Cells[10].Font.Bold = true;
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0))
    {
        cn.Open();
        DropDownList DropDownList1 = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlException") as DropDownList);
        TextBox tb1 = (e.Row.FindControl("ExceptionText") as TextBox);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].cr_fe_exception", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubTeamNo", SubTeam);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeasurementID", MeasurementID);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            a.Fill(dt);
        }

        cn.Close();
        DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "ExceptionDesc";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ExceptionID";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Exception--", "0"));


        if (CurrentException != "")
        {

            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(CurrentException).Value;
            tb1.Enabled = true;

        }
    }
}

protected void gvCaseList_edit(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

    Label label1 = (Label)gvCaseList.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("Label1");
    CurrentException = label1.Text;

    gvCaseList.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    GetgvCaseListData();

}

protected void gvCaseList_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtrslt = (DataTable)ViewState["dirState"];
    if (dtrslt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["sortdr"]) == "Asc")
        {
            dtrslt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Desc";
            ViewState["sortdr"] = "Desc";
        }
        else
        {
            dtrslt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Asc";
            ViewState["sortdr"] = "Asc";
        }
        gvCaseList.DataSource = dtrslt;
        gvCaseList.DataBind();

    }  

}
```

Comment: Added this line of code at the end of my sorting method after the data bind. 

Session["gridViewData"] = dtrslt.DefaultView.ToTable(); 

I changed my data source to point to the session in the edit event. This now works for when you edit a sorted view, but now no longer works when you edit the data grid view without sorting. Looks like I cant get it working for both cases (sorted and not sorted) :